# Apache Camel Kafka consumer consuming message even after pausing

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I have a `Kafka consumer` in `Camel` route which consumes the message as below:

```java
from("kafka:MykafkaTopic?brokers=localhost:9092&autoCommitEnable=false&allowManualCommit=true&maxPollRecords=1")
        .pausable(new KafkaConsumerListener(), o -> canContinue())
        .routeId("consumer")
            .log("    on the topic ${headers[kafka.TOPIC]}")
            .log("    on the partition ${headers[kafka.PARTITION]}")
            .log("    with the offset ${headers[kafka.OFFSET]}")
           // .to("direct:controlRoute")
        .to("direct:IncomingKafka")
        .end();
```

This method has to handle flow of pause:

```java
public  boolean canContinue() {
        if(count < 4) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getGlobal().info("count in canContinue::"+count);
            count++;
            return true;
        }
        if(count > 10) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getGlobal().info("count in canContinue::"+count);
            return true;
        } else {
            count++;
            java.util.logging.Logger.getGlobal().info("count in canContinue::"+count);
            return false;
        }
}
```

Based on the code, message consumption is expected to halt when the count is `greater than 4` and `less than 10`. However, the `Kafka consumer` continues to consume messages and discards them, indicating a pause between 4 and 10. I reached this conclusion by observing that the offset was consistently shifting, regardless of the consumer's state.

I was expecting the consumer would stop consuming the message when it is paused, and resume consumption from where it was paused.

Answer (score 0):

the pausable EIP is meant to pause the consumer when there is an [exception in the route](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/components/camel-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/kafka/consumer/support/KafkaRecordProcessorFacade.java#L91-L96) that prevents the exchange from being processed. More specifically, the check called by the `pausable` EIP should be used to test for transient conditions preventing the exchange from being processed.

So, what appears to be missing is an exception to be thrown somewhere in the `direct:IncomingKafka` route that causes the exchange to fail to be processed.

Based on this, I actually [adjusted the documentation](https://github.com/apache/camel/pull/12339) so that the purpose of the pausable EIP is clearer.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @otavio021, this explains the purpose of pausable EIP in kafka. I do have one more question, based on what you said i cant use pausable in my case, My use case is  "I have to pause the consumer based on a condition. I mean let's say i have a kafka consumer with consumerCount=1, every time i consume a message i need check a condition, if the condition is satisfied, I do a manual commit and continue my further processing. Else i want to pause the consumer . I want to run the check whether the consumer is paused or not, if paused then resume.Can you please provide any ideas

Comment: I don't think this use case is supported. You could try using `maxPollRecords=1`  and throw an exception if the condition is not satisfied.